# $diam(A)+diam(B)\leq diam(A\cup B)$ when $A \cap B= \varnothing$?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

Can someone please give me some hints on how to prove  $$diam (A)+ diam (B)\leq diam (A \cup B)$$ where $A \cap B=\varnothing$ and $A,B \subseteq \mathbb R^n.$  Here $diam (A)=\sup\{ d(x,y): x,y \in A\}$ and $d$ is the distant metric on $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: don't you mean $\ge$ and $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$?

Comment: The inequality may get reverse for non-empty, right?

Comment: Please don't use `\phi` to denote the empty set. The empty set symbol isn't derived from the Greek ϕ, it is derived from the Norwegian ø. The correct command is either `\varnothing` or `\emptyset` (depending on which look you prefer).

Comment: @nurun Yes, I spotted that only now. For empty intersection. there is little to infer for the union diameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n=1$, $A=[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$, and $B=[0,1]\setminus\mathbb Q$. We clearly have $\mathrm{diam}(A)=\mathrm{diam}(B)=\mathrm{diam}(A\cup B)=1$, so the inequality does not hold.

Comment: what is $n$ used for?

Comment: $n$ is the dimension $\mathbb R^n$ in the question.

Comment: I didn't realize Christoph already posted a counter-example, but I guess I will still leave this up.

Answer (score 3):

This is false. In $\mathbb R^2$ with the usual euclidean metric consider the two disjoint line segments $A=\{0\}\times[0,1]$ and $B=\{1\}\times[0,1]$. They both have diameter $1$ and their union $\{0,1\}\times[0,1]$ has diameter $\sqrt{2}\approx 1.414$.

Hence, in this case,
$$
\operatorname{diam}(A)+\operatorname{diam}(B) = 2 > \sqrt{2} = \operatorname{diam}(A\cup B).
$$

Really all you can say is that
$$
\operatorname{diam}(A\cup B) \ge \max(\operatorname{diam}(A), \operatorname{diam}(B)).
$$

Comment: Right. Or, in $\mathbb R^1$, take $A=\{0,2\}$ and $B=\{1,3\}$.